Graal vm null pointer exception on load native libraries in aws lambda
I use spring boot 3 and graalvm 23x
native image was built correctly but when I try to invoke rest method, I get the same error over and over again
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
2
2024-12-30T20:19:53.908Z
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 675.51 ms Phase: init Status: error Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
3
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.JNILibraryInitializer.callOnLoadFunction(JNILibraryInitializer.java:70)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
4
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.JNILibraryInitializer.initialize(JNILibraryInitializer.java:131)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
5
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.addLibrary(NativeLibrarySupport.java:128)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
6
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.addLibrary(NativeLibrarySupport.java:84)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
7
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary0(NativeLibraries.java:147)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
8
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibraries.loadLibraryAbsolute(NativeLibraries.java:102)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
9
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:116)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
10
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
11
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at java.base@23.0.1/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2028)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
12
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.runtimeapi.JniHelper.unpackAndLoad(JniHelper.java:51)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
13
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.runtimeapi.JniHelper.load(JniHelper.java:38)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
14
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.runtimeapi.NativeClient.init(NativeClient.java:16)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
15
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.runtimeapi.LambdaRuntimeApiClientImpl.<init>(LambdaRuntimeApiClientImpl.java:41)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
16
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:203)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
17
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:190)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
18
2024-12-30T20:19:53.905Z
... 1 more
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
19
2024-12-30T20:19:53.901Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.functions.JNIFunctions$Support.getFieldID(JNIFunctions.java:1858)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
20
2024-12-30T20:19:53.901Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.functions.JNIFunctions.GetFieldID(JNIFunctions.java:461)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
21
2024-12-30T20:19:53.901Z
at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.JNIOnLoadFunctionPointer.invoke(JNILibraryInitializer.java)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
22
2024-12-30T20:19:53.900Z
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
23
2024-12-30T20:19:53.898Z
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:192)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
24
2024-12-30T20:19:53.898Z
at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda.main(AWSLambda.java:180)
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
25
2024-12-30T20:19:53.894Z
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
2024/12/30/[96]d60ae33409494b2f916787fdb8d04cf9 
072301225383:/aws/lambda/kount-worker-stag
26
2024-12-30T20:19:53.319Z
LOGS Name: cloudwatch_lambda_agent State: Subscribed Types: [Platform]

Before that, I ran native agent
c:\projects\graalvm-jdk-23.0.1+11.1\bin\java.exe -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=META-INF/native-image -jar kount-worker.jar

and I used generated reachability-metadata.json file during the build.
My maven config:
<build>

        <finalName>kount-worker</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>--enable-preview</jvmArguments>
                    <compilerArguments>--enable-preview</compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-aot</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-aot</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <excludes>-->
<!--                        <exclude>-->
<!--                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>-->
<!--                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>-->
<!--                        </exclude>-->
<!--                    </excludes>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->

<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>repackage</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-native</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-native</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
<!--                    <mainClass>com.eye4fraud.kount.KountApplication</mainClass>-->
                    <mainClass>com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda</mainClass>
                    <imageName>kount-worker</imageName>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <buildArg>-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=src/main/resources/proxies.json</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>--emit build-report</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-Os</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-H:-ReduceImplicitExceptionStackTraceInformation</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=src/main/resources/resource-config.json</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>-H:JNIConfigurationFiles=src/main/resources/jni-config.json</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>--verbose</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>--enable-url-protocols=http</buildArg>
<!--                        <buildArg>-march=native</buildArg>-->
                        <buildArg>-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=src/main/resources/reflect-config.json</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>
                            --initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider
                        </buildArg>
                        <buildArg>--enable-all-security-services</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>--enable-http</buildArg>
                        <buildArg>--enable-https</buildArg>
                    </buildArgs>


                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.3.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                            <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>
                        --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>23</source>
                    <target>23</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <finalName>kount-worker</finalName>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--                <version>3.2.0</version>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>kount-worker</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

I also have reachability-json file in resources META-INF/native-image/groupid/artifactid
I am tired trying to understand what this NPE comes from. Please help
